# Asp.net Identity Boa prática autorização

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho meu usuário usando asp.net identity para autenticação
como de costume eu tenho minha classe implementando IUser

```
public class usuario: IUser 
{
public User(){...}

        public User(string userName) (){...}

        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
}
```

Ok, eu também tenho minha classe Pessoa

Aonde todos os meus cadastros (cliente, fornecedor, vendedor, etc) herdam de Pessoa.

A minha dúvida é:

Seria uma má prática eu implementar o IUser numa classe de herda pessoa?

```
Public class usuario: Pessoa,IUser {
}
```

Ou apenas ter uma classe para ligar ambas entidades, fazendo assim, a PESSOA Y tem um usuário no sistema

```
public class UsuarioPessoa {

public Pessoa Pessoa {get;set;}
public usuario usuario {get;set;}
}
```

A principio um Vendedor que herda de Pessoa, iré ter um usuário para fazer login no sistema. e apenas 1.

Comment: De fato depende de como você pretende implementar essas relações, outra ideia (que eu utilizo) é ter uma dependência opcional de Pessoa em Usuario, ou vice-versa: `public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }`. Eu evitaria o segundo exemplo, pois podem haver casos de uma Pessoa ter relações com um ou mais Usuarios e também vice-versa. A não ser que isso seja desejável.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende do seu objetivo.

Concordo de `Pessoa` e `Usuário` serem separados se `Pessoa` não precisar ter um `Usuário`, ou então se uma `Pessoa` possuir vários `Usuários` (2º exemplo).

Caso contrário, o melhor é implementar tudo na classe `Pessoa` (1º exemplo).

Comment: A principio um Vendedor que herda de Pessoa, iré ter um usuário para fazer login no sistema. e apenas 1.